# Tourism on Schengen business visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, change-purpose-of-travel

I am an Indian citizen living in UK on a tier 2 visa. Recently, I have received Short stay Schengen visas (multiple entry, business trips for 1 year) for travelling to France. (Applied at French embassy Edinburgh)

Unfortunately, the tickets I have provided in my visa application needs to be cancelled as my business trip got cancelled. And I will be travelling for business probably after 4 months.

So, for now, I am planning my first entry to France for tourism purpose.

Is it okay to travel with Short stay Schengen visas (business) for tourism purpose for the very first entry to France?

I am worried because my itinerary provided for visa application is changed now. And moreover it is now for a tourism purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my understanding from my stay as under a Schengen visa, the time starts from the initial visit, so if it's tourism, that's fine, but it will count against your count of days (as does tourism in other Schengen countries).

If you can move the start date of the Schengen visa back, that would be best, but you can use your Schengen days for tourism if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am back after my trip without any issue. I mailed embassy regarding the change, but they replied with link to understand Schengen visa.