# Can a business visa be used for tourism in schengen states

Tags: visas, schengen, business-travel

I have a Schengen business visa. Can I travel as a tourist to the Schengen states or do I need to apply again for a tourist visa?

Comment: What does the official documentation say? I'd rather rely on that than the word of strangers on a Q&A site, personally. For Q&A, already asked here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16031/tourism-on-schengen-business-visa-circulation

Comment: The most important distinction is between long-validity multiple-entry (sometimes called “circulation”) visa and short one- or two-entry visa. With the former, it should not be an issue, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27672/can-i-travel-to-spain-using-a-greek-schengen-visa-even-if-i-dont-want-to-stay-i?lq=1 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/use-of-unused-schengen-visa-to-travel-to-switzerland?lq=1

Comment: To the “close” voters: We don't actually know if that a question is a duplicate of the previous one. If you feel compelled to close it as duplicate, I provided better choices.