# Can I use a Schengen multiple-entry business visa for tourism?

Tags: visas, germany, multiple-entry, business-travel, norway

I have a valid multiple entry schengen business visa issued by the norwegian embassy for a duration of 1 year.

I was supposed to travel at the beginning of February to Norway and use this visa but unfortunately my business trip got cancelled. Therefore, I have not used this visa so far.

I wanted to know if I can use this visa for tourism and now can I enter Germany through this visa as it is valid for a year and is multiple entry visa for all schengen states ?

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16031/tourism-on-schengen-business-visa-circulation

Comment: The country-of-first-entry question isn't a duplicate at all, the issues are *very* different. See rather http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/use-of-unused-schengen-visa-to-travel-to-switzerland and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point

Comment: If the tourism is incidental then yes. But based upon what you wrote, you would not be about to enter Schengen under the same circumstances for which your visa was issued.  Hence not advisable...

Comment: In reality, this is a duplicate of [Can I use my Schengen visa for a completely different purpose and entry point?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26939/11491)